# How to parse a json string to a case class in scaja.js and vice versa

Tags: json, scala.js

A JSON string:

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 111
}
```

A case class:

```
case class User(name:String, age:Int)
```

If I use scala, there are many libraries can let me convert the JSON to the case class and vice versa, but they can't be used in scala.js.

How to do this work in scala.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use one of the pickling libraries that work with Scala.js. The following two produce well-behaved and predictable JSON:

- [uPickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle)
- [Prickle](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle)

Comment: Thanks for recommending this, they are just what I'm looking for. And just found the author of `Prickle` is my friend ...

Comment: Deprecated repository for uPickle/PPrint. PPrint now lives at https://github.com/lihaoyi/pprint, and uPickle is deprecated in favor of https://github.com/playframework/play-json

Answer (score 1):

`Circe` has more than 1000 stars:
https://github.com/circe/circe

Comment: circe, can we used with scalajs as some other inherent java libs may required when import jar packages in scvalajs client side during  final bundle js generataed with fatOptJS/fullOptJS.  It may cause issue?

Comment: uPickle is faster than Play-Json, Circe, or Argonaut by a large margin.

Answer (score 1):

More safe and efficient options are:

- [AVSystems GenCodec](https://github.com/AVSystem/scala-commons/blob/master/docs/GenCodec.md)
- [Borer](https://github.com/sirthias/borer)
- [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala)

Bellow are results of [benchmarks for parsing and serialization](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/c94a5c20be928789ffd8b3ebe189fa8ee9e9ae61/jsoniter-scala-benchmark/js/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/benchmark/Main.scala#L1025-L1043) of [a message sample](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/c94a5c20be928789ffd8b3ebe189fa8ee9e9ae61/jsoniter-scala-benchmark/shared/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/benchmark/TwitterAPIBenchmark.scala#L12-L439) from [the Twitter API](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/c94a5c20be928789ffd8b3ebe189fa8ee9e9ae61/jsoniter-scala-benchmark/shared/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/benchmark/TwitterAPI.scala):

[image: Twitter API Reading]
[image: Twitter API Writing]